SSIS issue with inserting decimals into Oracle. Changing the values to fill up precision length?
Here is my scenario:

SQL Server 2019
Flat file source (delimited .txt file)
Oracle destination
Example value in source file is "2.2"
Flat file source column type is double-precision float (DT_R8)
Value is being stored in Oracle destination as "2.20000005"
Oracle destination column is defined as Float(126)

I am able to perform this derived column expression to get around problem ((DT_NUMERIC,16,4)ROUND([Column_Name], 4)), but I have a LOT of columns like this, and I'm wondering if there is an easier way.
